# Checkbox, unselect and select

Tags: jquery

What I want is when checkbox1 is selected both checkbox labelled 1 will get selected and background will be removed

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/D2vCf/)

for eg if i select checkbox1 it should select both checkbox labelled checkbox1

Comment: How long did you spend formatting that question? < 10 seconds?

Comment: i thought the question i wrote in Word Format will maintain the formatting

Comment: Almost never cut-and-paste from a word processor into something expecting plain text. Stick to plain text, and use the formatting provided by the site :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that searching for ID $("#somethin") is not possible to select more than one element. IF you search for class, then your example works.. well, with [some minor changes](http://jsfiddle.net/D2vCf/11/) :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        var pos;
        pos = this.id;

       // global hook - unblock UI when ajax request completes
        $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);


        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("."+pos).parent().removeClass("highlight");
            $("."+pos).prop('checked', true)

            //ajax to add uni
        } else {
            //ajax to remove uni
            $("."+pos).parent().addClass("highlight");
            $("."+pos).prop('checked', false)


        }
    });

 });
```

Comment: agreed... your comments did help me figure out my problem +1 , accepted answer

Comment: (Yours is more generic than mine, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple DOM elements with the same id.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PL6MW/1/) for a working example, but it's not as generic as you may need.

Answer (score 0):

Select multiple elements using class. You can try this..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#checkbox1").click(function () {
             $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
         });
     });
</script>
```

and your html code will be like below

```
<div>
   <table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="highlight"/></td>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>

</table>
    </div>
```